# operations in determinant

Tags: determinant, control-theory, prime-factorization, coprime

I want to simplify a condition inside a determinant using coprime factorisations and I need to know if an operation is mathematically correct. This is a simplification of what I'm actually doing, but I only need to know if the last step is okay. I hope it is clear enough such that someone can give me feedback.

Let $A  = M^{-1}N$ and $B = XY^{-1}$, these are all nonzero $n\times n$ matrices. Let $D$ also be another $n \times n$ matrix and let $\phi$ be a scalar.
These are the steps that I am taking, where I am using that det$(AB) = $ det$(A)$det$(B)$ for $n \times n$ matrices:
\begin{align}
\text{det}\big(I - D(I + AB)^{-1} \big)\phi & \neq 0 \\
\text{multiply lhs and rhs by det$(I + AB)$} \\
\text{det}\big(I + AB - D)\phi & \neq 0 \\
\text{substitute $A  = M^{-1}N$ and $B = XY^{-1}$ } \\
\text{det}\big(I + M^{-1}NXY^{-1} - D)\phi & \neq 0 \\
\text{multiply lhs and rhs by det$(M)$ from left side and det$(Y)$ from right side} \\
\text{det}(M)\cdot \text{det}\big(I + M^{-1}NXY^{-1} - D)  \cdot \text{det}(Y) \neq \text{det}(M)\cdot 0 &\cdot \text{det}(Y) \\
\text{det}\big(MY + NX - MDY \big)\phi & \neq 0 \\
\text{Move $\phi$ inside determinant} \\
\text{det}\big(MY\phi^{1/n} + NX\phi^{1/n} - MDY\phi^{1/n} \big) & \neq 0 
\end{align}

Is step three mathematically correct?

Comment: The last step will not be correct unless $\phi=\phi^n$. For a scalar $\phi$ and an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ the following holds: $\det{(\phi A)}=\phi^n\det{A}$. So if you're moving $\phi$ into the determinant, then in the determinant it has to come with the $n$-th root.

Comment: I see, so when I put $\phi$ inside the determinant, it becomes $\phi^{1/n}$. I just tried it numerically, thanks Randy.

Comment: You also have to be careful that $\det M=0$ or $\det Y=0$ isn't the case.

Comment: Yes, in my problem I assume that M and Y are nonzero. Thanks for the heads up, I'll add it to my description.

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I see that at the beginning you have $M^{-1}$ and $Y^{-1}$, so their determinant must be non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that $I+AB$ is invertible and $\phi\ne0$.

Multiplying an invertible matrix by an invertible matrix yields an invertible matrix. Thus all the matrices below are invertible if the top one is:
\begin{align}
& I-D(I+AB)^{-1} \\
& (I-D(+AB)^{-1})(I+AB) \\
& I+AB-D \\
& I+M^{-1}NXY^{-1}-D \\
& M(I+M^{-1}NXY^{-1}-D)Y \\
& MY+NX-MDY \\
& (MY+NX-MDY)\phi
\end{align}
Therefore $\det((MY+NX-MDY)\phi)\ne0$.